# sublime text - coloring files according to their revision status

Tags: git, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Other editors, such as PyCharm and Atom offer a feature where files are colored differently according to their status on git (one color marks a file as modified, another as unrevisioned, etc.). This is an extremely useful feature. Is there a way to get that on sublime as well? The two other editors I've mentioned are just too heavy to be enjoyable.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [`Git`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Git) plugin, available via Package Control. Among many other things, it shows the current branch and the status of the file in Sublime's status bar:

[image: git status bar]

Here are the status bar symbols:

```js
{
    "modified": "≠", 
    "added": "+", 
    "deleted": "×", 
    "untracked": "?", 
    "conflicts": "‼", 
    "renamed":"R", 
    "copied":"C", 
    "clean": "√", 
    "separator": " "
}
```

which can be changed in the package's settings.

Additionally, you might be interested in the [`GitGutter`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/GitGutter) package, which indicates added, removed, and changed lines in the gutter (to the left of the line numbers):

[image: GitGutter]

For more git-related packages, just [search Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/search/git).

Comment: Nope. thanks, but not what I'm looking for. None of those change the color of the files themselves, which is the most important aspect

Comment: @yuvi what exactly do you mean by "the color of the files"?

Comment: [like this](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/file-status-highlights.html). see how the panel on the left looks [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/screenshots/27/pycharm_ui_darcula.png)

Comment: @yuvi OK, I understand. To the best of my knowledge, this is not currently possible in Sublime, due to the lack of an official side bar API. The font and font color are defined in whichever theme you are using, but are not accessible programmatically. I think icons can be changed, but they are based on file type, so I don't think you can assign a specific icon to a specific file.

Comment: bummer. I thought that at the very least I could implement this myself but not even that... Oh well. That's what you get for using closed-sourced software, no matter how good it is. You got a +1 from me, but I'm leaving the question unanswered, in the hope that this will change at some point

Comment: @yuvi thanks for the +1. Since there are people who know more about Sublime's internals than me who aren't regularly on SO, you might want to ask your question in the [Sublime Forum](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/) and see what sort of responses you get.